# Why? TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.FB.getLoginStatus')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, next.js

I would NOT use react-facebook-login now, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login

but I would implement in my Next.js / React app Facebook login based on standard Facebook instruction, I can find on Facebook Developer site.

[image]

I have added `script` in `_document.tsx`. I have Next.js, script goes there:

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
                                window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                                    FB.init({
                                      appId      : '2773133082797983',
                                      cookie     : true,
                                      xfbml      : true,
                                      version    : 'v14.0'
                                    });
                                      
                                    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
                            `,
  }}
/>
```

But how can I perform following call? `FB.getLoginStatus(`

This is I tried, based on this video: https://morioh.com/p/6ef9c92aebd1

```
<a
  className="btn btn-sm text-bold btn-circle shadow-1 full-width-sm"
  onClick={() => {
    window.FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }}
>
  Bejelentkezem
</a>
```

Is this the right way to do it?

I got following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.FB.getLoginStatus')
```

I tried to call `FB.login(` also, same result.

Comment: Did you actually embed the SDK as well? Are you sure the script element content you inserted with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` actually executed?

Comment: yes, you are right, I forget copy-paste all the js code, forget the SDK part